# <section> tag move down when there is not enough room at screen

Tags: html, css, web

I have to section tags. When there is space for both I want them to be side by side But When there is not enough space for both I want the second to be below the first one.

What css/flex box properties do I have to use?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

**Edited:**

**SIMPLE HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="section_logo">

    <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.gif"/>

</section>  

<section id="section_login">

    <img id="logo" src="images/Logo.gif"/>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:box;

display: -ms-flexbox;           /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex;          /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

width:100%;

-webkit-box-pack:center;    /*Cuando el monitor es mayor al sitio centra el sitio.*/

-webkit-box-orient: vertical;

background-image: url(../images/FondoPantalla.png);

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
 }

#section_logo{
display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:box;

-webkit-flex: 1;                /* Chrome */
-ms-flex: 1;                    /* IE 10 */
flex: 1;   

position: relative;

width:50%;
  }

#section_login{
display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
display:-ms-flexbox; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:box;

-webkit-flex: 1;                /* Chrome */
-ms-flex: 1;                    /* IE 10 */
flex: 1;   

position: relative;

width:50%;
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and what goes wrong.

Comment: Since the width of each box is set to `50%`, I don't think they'll ever fail to fit in the browser. Instead, the widths will just shrink down to nothing. Is that the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends tremendously on what specifics you need.  If you just need two square content blocks side-by-side that stack vertically with a small enough window, use `display: inline-block` on those blocks.

http://jsfiddle.net/sHNjm/

Comment: The two sections goes together and occupy the same space. I mean the second one doesn't do down..

Comment: Thanks! The jfiddle helped